# При появлении клавиатуры NavigationBar появляется над клавиатурой

Tags: android, xml, navigationbar

NavigationBar поднимается над клавиатурой, а должен бать под ней

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

fragment xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/main_color"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".ui.fragments.CreateFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/name"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/game_name"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="50">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_edit_text"
            android:maxLength="50"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/description"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/game_description"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:counterEnabled="true"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:counterMaxLength="500">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/description_edit_text"
            android:maxLength="500"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/author"
        style="@style/author" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/game_author"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/design_default_color_error"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/author_spinner"
            android:inputType="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        


  style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="@string/game_genre"
        app:helperTextEnabled="true"
        app:helperTextTextColor="@color/design_default_color_error"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/genre_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="none" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

        />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Activity xml:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ui.BaseActivity"
android:background="@color/main_color">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/game_list"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="35sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation_bar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/label"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_bar" />


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_bar"
    style="@style/navigationBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/main_color"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/icons_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_material" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Пробывал вставлять android:isScrollContainer="false" не помогло

Как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: Это связанно с ScrollView т.к. раньше был FrameLayout и было все хорошо

Comment: Попробуйте удалить из `AndroidManifest.xml` строчку `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` в блоке объявления активити

Comment: @SelectionForCollection не у меня такой строчки

Comment: тогда попробуйте добавить `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` или же `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"`. Тогда окно не будет масштабироваться для показа метода ввода.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо)))